# CGContext erase with some alpha value

Tags: alpha, cgcontext, erase

I can easily draw and erase on a UIImage using CGContext.

For erasing, I use

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear);
```

and draw along the path. This erases whatever drawing that is
on the image, completely.

What I want to do is to have it erase softly, so user must stroke 
at the same place 3-4-5 times before it is completely gone.

Any idea how to do this and is it possible, even?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself but how about using blend mode kCGBlendModeMultiply then drawing with the color (r:1, g:1, b:1, a:0.5)?